# Understanding classification of discontinuities

Tags: calculus, continuity

$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ , let  $\displaystyle f\left(x\right)\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2-8x+15} & x\ne 3,5 \\0 & x=3,5\end{pmatrix}$.

I need to Find all the discontinuities and classify them.

I'm not really sure what to do,  because it $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
What can i say about $x=3,5$?

Comment: For all $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and for all $x\not \in \left\{3,\frac 7 2, 5\right\}$, $f$ is continuous at $x$. Do you realise this?

Comment: but how you can prove this? and why 7/2?

Comment: Judging by the kind of problem it is, it's sensible to assume that you can use the fact that the product and sum of continuous functions is continuous. What do you mean with 'why $\frac 7 2$?'?

Comment: you wrote that for 7/2 is not continuous

Comment: No, I didn't say what happens at $\frac 7 2$, I just indicated some points in which the function is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discontinuities depend on $a$ and $b$.

If $x-3$ divides the numerator, $f(x)$ has a limit at $x=3$; otherwise, not. Similarly with $x-5$ and $x=5$. The function will be *continuous* if, in addition, the limit is zero. Note that if $x-3$ divides the numerator, the numerator is then $(x-3)(x-c)$ for some $c$, and you can easily see what $a$ and $b$ are then.

Now set conditions on $a$ and $b$ based on those statements. You will get up to four possibilities: $f(x)$ continuous everywhere except at $3$ and $5$, everywhere except $3$, everywhere except $5$, and everywhere. Check carefully, as some of these may not be actual possibilities.

Do you need more hints?

(Note: my original answer was incorrect.)

---

We can easily see that $f(x)$ is continuous where $x$ is neither $3$ nor $5$. A quotient of continuous functions is continuous except where the denominator is zero. Polynomials are continuous, so this applies to your $f(x)$, and if $x$ is neither $3$ nor $5$ the denominator is not zero (since the denominator is $(x-3)(x-5))$.